extend execution time limit in Spring Batch
I have a big problem here, Spring Batch + TaskExecutor doesn't execute a thread by more than 10 minutes and of course that I need that eventually the batch job should take 2 hours if necessary.
Y just do:
java -jar receip-processor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev

And exactly after 10 minutes:
2024-04-10T13:59:41.798-03:00  INFO 26072 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value 2147483647 within timeout of 600000ms: [taskExecutor1]

600000ms is the equivalent to 10 minutes.
The config of taskExecutor is pretty standard:
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor1() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(10000);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(25);      
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("taskExecutor1-prueba-");
    taskExecutor.initialize();
    
    return taskExecutor;
}

but how can I extend the timeout of the bean, to 3 hours for example?
I've already tried with:
    taskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(10000);
    taskExecutor.setKeepAliveSeconds(10800);

That is, set timeout to 3 hours.
